# Syslog-ng compilation on AIX

Tags: aix, syslog-ng

I am trying to compile syslog-ng 3.6.1. on the following system configurations.
./configure goes fine. but make gives me  below errors, please help!

oslevel -s
7100-02-03-1334

aclocal --version
aclocal (GNU automake) 1.14.1

bison --version
bison (GNU Bison) 3.0

gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.3

m4 --version
m4 (GNU M4) 1.4.17

CC       librabbitmq/librabbitmq_librabbitmq_la-amqp_api.lo

In file included from ./librabbitmq/unix/socket.h:38:0, from librabbitmq/amqp_private.h:84,
 from librabbitmq/amqp_api.c:37:

librabbitmq/amqp_private.h:229:42: error: expected ')' before 'val' static inline uint64_t func##ll(uint64_t val) \ ^

librabbitmq/amqp_private.h:244:1: note: in expansion of macro 'DECLARE_XTOXLL'
 DECLARE_XTOXLL(hton) ^

librabbitmq/amqp_private.h:229:42: error: expected ')' before 'val'
 static inline uint64_t func##ll(uint64_t val) \ ^

librabbitmq/amqp_private.h:245:1: note: in expansion of macro 'DECLARE_XTOXLL'
 DECLARE_XTOXLL(ntoh) ^
Makefile:1441: recipe for target 'librabbitmq/librabbitmq_librabbitmq_la-amqp_api.lo' failed

make[2]: *** [librabbitmq/librabbitmq_librabbitmq_la-amqp_api.lo] Error 1

make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/tufail/workspace/syslog/syslog-ng-3.6.1/modules/afamqp/rabbitmq-c'

Makefile:959: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tufail/workspace/syslog/syslog-ng-3.6.1/modules/afamqp/rabbitmq-c'

Makefile:11222: recipe for target 'modules/afamqp/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq/librabbitmq.la' failed

make: *** [modules/afamqp/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq/librabbitmq.la] Error 2

Comment: Hi, I got below error when i disabled amqp.
lib/nvtable.c:559:12: error: expected expression before '.' token

lib/nvtable.c:564:94: error: 't_union' undeclared (first use in 
this function)

   return func(handle, nv_registry_get_handle_name(registry, handle, NULL), value, value_len, func_data);

lib/nvtable.c:564:94: note: each undeclared identifier is reported 
only once for each function it appears in lib/nvtable.c:565:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]}
make[2]: *** [lib/lib_libsyslog_ng_la-nvtable.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 make: **

Answer (score 0):

it seems that it cannot compile the rabbitmq library (used by the AMQP destination). If you do not use AMQP, you can disable it with the --disable-amqp compile option. If it doesn't help, I'd recommend posting the problem to the developers at the [syslog-ng mailing list](https://lists.balabit.hu/mailman/listinfo/syslog-ng/)

Regards,

Robert Fekete